# Django CMS blog - Replacing templates for different cases

Tags: django, templates, django-cms

I'm not sure, Django CMS Blog is complete app or foundation for self-extending ? I can see one huge logical mistake - inside one app config, I can't easy change template - for list, detail, archive and item - they are strict and hardcoded in plugin code.
Is there any way to customize it without hacking the app/writing tons of custom plugins ?

I need several versions for each template - especially for blog_item.html, blog_detail.html and blog_archive.html.
I want to use plugin feature from Django CMS and don't want to hardcode whole layout in template include logic because this is broking MVC logic (!).

OK, I know, I can include my custom subtemplate blog_item in list template with instance varibles, but I totaly can't imagine, how to do it in several places - front page, list page, post page etc BUT using regular Django CMS plugin features - I have static placeholders and tpl blocks - but there still is one template for item, inside app code.
I understand (less/more) Django template inheritance, but this case is more complicated than simple inheritance between templates.

At frontpage I want different list of latest posts - one template
at category list - different layout - so next template,
inside post - detail_view - need to be customized in other way.

Can somebody guide me, how to achieve this ? Custom plugin for each layout case or something ? A bunch of IF statement in template, dependend from contex is ridiculous..

---

I have replaced templates set, for app config - configured templates prefix, and whole folder with `articles/*.html` files. But changing item subtemplate cause change layout part in many places in the same time. This is main problem. Each using "latest posts" plugin, use same template - and I can't set template files for each plugin instance.

---

After some tests and talks, there is no nice way to replace templates, except extending plugin class and write own better version of plugin...